# When switching between branches in VS Code, changes persist when they shouldn't

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code IDE. I have a brand new branch off master, made some small changes in one file, committed them to my new branch. Then checked out master, however all the changes I made are still visible in the file I edited except with a green banner next to them that I think indicates that VSC sees these edits as new unsaved or uncommitted changes.

Normally when I check out a new branch, the file displayed is just that, the file without any forced additions. But now my IDE is taking changes I made (both additions and subtractions) and copying them into the same file of another branch and it's infuriating.

Demonstration:

mycode.py in master:

```
def main():
    print('hi')
```

mycode.py in mybranch:

```
def main():
    print('hi')
    print('this is a change made to mycode.py')
```

User stages and commits changes to mybranch then checkouts out master. VSCode displays mycode.py *on master* as:

```
def main():
    print('hi')
|    print('this is a change made to mycode.py')
```

except the pipe to the left of the added line is a green banner

Comment: Can you post screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of VSCODE, the green bar would only show temporarily, when the file is revisited they will disappear.

Nonetheless, as far as new sub-directory is of concern, when switching back to the main branch, the directory created in the new branch will still be seen, but not the files. However, the directory structure in the IDE of codespaces will synchronize with the new branch 100%. That is the new directory created in the new branch would not be shown at all.